# Request timeout in Gatling

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I am using maven to run my Gatling (Scala) performance test.

It gives me request timeout issue when I increase user from 100 to 150.

If I set the number of user to 300, then I get following error in simulation log.

```
// Gatling scenario injection
val scn =  scenario("UATEnvironmentTest")
.exec(http("AdminLoginRequest")
.post("/authorization_microservice/oauth/token")
.headers(headers_1).body(RawFileBody("Login.txt"))
.check(jsonPath("$.access_token")
.saveAs("auth_token")))
.pause(2)  

setUp(scn.inject(nothingFor(5 seconds),atOnceUsers(50),rampUsers(250) over(10 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

> Error :- j.u.c.TimeoutException: Read timeout to /IP:80 after 120000
>   ms GROUP  Failed to build request Request_1:  No attribute named
>   'auth_token' is defined

Following is the configuration:

```
//Maven configuration-pom.xml
java.version 1.8
gatling.version 2.2.3
gatling-plugin.version 2.2.1
scala-maven-plugin.version 3.2.2
// Gatling.conf file
connectTimeout 120000                         
handshakeTimeout 120000                       
pooledConnectionIdleTimeout 120000                  
readTimeout 120000                             
requestTimeout 120000
```

Comment: Hi , I increased following values.  connectTimeout = 600000                          
      handshakeTimeout = 600000                       
      pooledConnectionIdleTimeout = 600000            
      readTimeout = 600000                                      requestTimeout = 600000. Result are promising to me . Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Phonolog

Comment: The error is "No attribute named 'auth_token'" and not what you are looking

Answer (score 6):

For your particular case, the error is what already mentioned by @user666 in the comment section, but if you wanted to increase the request time out of Gatling Scripts, so that the connection stays:

1. Edit the Gatling.conf file
2. Uncomment the requestTimeout line
3. Provide the time in milliseconds you wanted your connection to be kept alive